# update column value in table by selecting same table column value

Tags: sql, jsp

I am trying to update download_count in my web app.i tried this way

```
update  data_files  d set d.download_count=(select f.download_count from data_files f  where f.filename='file.txt')+1 where d.filename='file.txt'
```

but not update column value.Can this have alternative Solution

Comment: did you tried your query in database? what it is giving?

Comment: You can't specify target table 'd' for update in FROM clause

Comment: update test t set t.download_count= (select f.download_countfrom test f where f.filename='file.txt')+1 where t.filename like 'file.txt'; working in derby for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify this to:

```
update  data_files  d 
set d.download_count= d.download_count+1
where d.filename = 'file.txt'
```